# Cookies saved in Postman but not in browser(Next.js) after uploading to AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, google-chrome, cors

I have been trying to solve this issue for the past two days already, but still, no success. None of the answers provided here have resolved my issue regarding cookies in the response in the browser.

I have Node.js (Express.js) code which works fine on my local machine **localhost:8088**. I receive cookies in the browser when the user logs in.

However, after uploading my code to an AWS EC2 nginx server, I am not able to get cookies in my browser, although I am able to receive them in Postman. Can someone assist me with this issue?

**Express.js**

```
const attachCookiesToResponse = ({ res, user, refreshToken }) => {
  const accessTokenJWT = createJWT({ payload: { user } })
  const refreshTokenJWT = createJWT({ payload: { user, refreshToken } })

  const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  const oneWeek = oneDay * 7

  res.cookie('accessToken', accessTokenJWT, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    signed: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + oneDay)
  })

  res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshTokenJWT, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    signed: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + oneWeek)
  })
}
```

Next.js

```
export const requestLogin = async (body: unknown) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(apiEndpoint.login(), body, {
      withCredentials: true,
    });
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

Comment: Are the client and server [_same-site_](https://site-and-origin.securitum.com/)? If not, you'll need to set the cookie with `SameSite=None` (which also requires the `Secure` cookie attribute in modern browsers).

Comment: I have tried SmaeSite=None, it didn't work. Server site is in AWS ec2, client site is localhost.

Comment: Did you try to set the cookie with a `Secure` attribute too? `SameSite=None` will only be accepted by modern browsers if the cookie is also set with `Secure`. Of course, your server will need to support HTTPS for `Secure` to work.

Comment: as you can see my code above, i tried secure: true, as well. But my api is not https, it is http? so i need to make it https in aws?

Comment: Yes, only secure origins (https) are allowed by browsers to set a `Secure` cookie.

Comment: even for when i try on localhost:3000, i need Secure cookie?

Comment: If the server attempting to set the cookie runs on http://localhost:3000, browsers will reject such attempts. `SameSite=None` requires `Secure`, which requires a `https` origin. You write that your production server runs on AWS EC2. You'll need to obtain and install a TLS certificate for it if you want things to work. Alternatively, deploy your frontend to a domain that's [same-site](https://site-and-origin.securitum.com/) with your AWS EC2 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was resolved after getting SSL certificate.